# Animation on initial page load only

Tags: jquery, css, animation, cookies

I currently have a CSS animation that fades in my whole index.html when it is visited.

What I want to do is only have this happen when someone is visiting from an external site. If they are navigating back to the homepage from another of my site's pages, I will only animate those elements which have changed, leaving things like the marquee and the footer static.

I would like to know whether this is practically possible, and how it would be implemented - jQuery, cookies? as I like the fade in when coming from another site as it helps smooth the loading of elements, however its a bit clumsy when navigating from page to page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to animate the opacity of the body tag once.

Firefox will remember that the animation ran already, so when you go back to the cached page it won't run again. Other browsers (Chrome) will re-run the animation. To avoid this, you need to key the animation to an ID or class and have a snippet of JavaScript in the body tag to check a cookie.

```js
if(false == /(^|;)\s?first=1\s?($|;)/i.test(document.cookie)) {
    document.body.id="first";
    document.cookie = "first=1; expire= path=/";
}
```

```css
#first {
    animation: fadeInOnce 1s 1 ease; 
}
    
@keyframes fadeInOnce { 
    0% { 
        display: none; 
        opacity: 0; 
    } 
    100% { 
        display: block; 
        opacity: 1; 
    } 
}
```

```html
<div id="first">This is content</div>
```